# How do I use LINQ on a stored procedure with a Select statement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, return-value, store

How do I use LINQ on a stored procedure with a `Select` statement?

I know how can I use stored procedure to execute some procedure for me, however, if I want to return some data from a stored procedure? How do I do that?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Scott Guthrie has a [fairly detailed blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) about this. Normally I believe you'd call a stored procedure as a separate method - if you want to include it in a select clause, you should probably use a user-defined function (UDF) instead. These are covered in the same blog post.

If you've already read this and it doesn't help, could you give details of which part isn't working for you?